# TSQL CTE Maxrecursion over workaround?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table which has over 4M records. I want to break records down by specific column however I hit maxrecusion limit of 32767. Is there a way to break records down without using CTE. I tried temp table and while loop approach however my new data set should be called in a view so #temp table and table variables are not helping me at all.

Base table:

```
select 
     ID,
     CAST(start_time AS datetime) AS start_time,
     DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime))  AS end_time
     ,duration
FROM 
    dbo.RunTable  
where id =1
```

OutPut:

```
ID  start_time  end_time        duration
1   2009-12-10  13:50:34.000    2009-12-10 18:21:09.000 16235
```

Query With CTE:

```
WITH  td_run_base (ID,start_time,end_time1,end_time) AS
(SELECT  ID,
     CAST(start_time AS datetime) AS start_time,
     DATEADD(ss, 60*60, CAST(start_time AS datetime)) AS end_time1,
     DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime))  AS end_time
FROM 
    dbo.RunTable 
where Id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        ID,
        DATEADD(ss, 0, end_time1) as start_time,
        DATEADD(ss, 60*60,end_time1) AS end_time1,
        end_time
FROM td_run_base WHERE CAST(end_time1 AS datetime) < CAST(end_time
AS   datetime)
),
td_run_cte AS
(SELECT ID,start_time,
CASE WHEN end_time1 > end_time THEN end_time ELSE end_time1 END AS end_time
FROM td_run_base)
SELECT td_run_cte.ID,
   td_run_cte.start_time,
   td_run_cte.end_time,
   datediff(ss,start_time,end_time) as Duration
 FROM 
   td_run_cte
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767) -- maxrecursion for sql server standard 
 go
```

Output:

```
ID     start_time                end_time          Duration
1   2009-12-10 13:50:34.000 2009-12-10 14:50:34.000 3600
1   2009-12-10 14:50:34.000 2009-12-10 15:50:34.000 3600
1   2009-12-10 15:50:34.000 2009-12-10 16:50:34.000 3600
1   2009-12-10 16:50:34.000 2009-12-10 17:50:34.000 3600
1   2009-12-10 17:50:34.000 2009-12-10 18:21:09.000 1835
```

My initial thought was to create a view using this query however I have over 4 Million records in that table and I certainly can't use #temp tables in the view. Is there a way to work around it. I create a static table using temp tables and while loop and call that table from a view. However, it is the approach I should not be following due to permission given me. It can only be a query or a view .

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by break records down by specific column?  Maybe sample data and output would help, and the query you're using now would help too.

Comment: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.  As for your question about changing the query, sample data, desired results, and the current query would all help other people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maximums on recursion exist for a reason, often to halt endless loops. If your data has an inherent hierarchy in it, do you really expect to need 32767 levels in that hierarchy? Re-think what you are attempting and as already stated: please provide sample data + expected result + existing query

Comment: You can always use a Numbers table to avoid the CTEs

Comment: Numbers table? You meant temp table or table variables ?

Comment: [Table of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). A permanent table that has enough rows for your purposes, say, 100K rows or 1M rows. But, it is not clear what your query does/should do. Maybe you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the recursion by using a numbers table (just a table that holds values from 1-n).  `Table1` in my query represents the output of your first query, so you'll have to use a subquery/cte, similarly if you can't build a numbers table you'll have to use a cte/subquery for that too:

```
    SELECT a.ID
      ,DATEADD(hour,n-1,start_time) AS Start_Time
      ,CASE WHEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time) <= End_Time THEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time)
            ELSE End_Time      
       END as End_Time
      ,DATEDIFF(ss,DATEADD(hour,n-1,start_time),CASE WHEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time) <= End_Time THEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time)
            ELSE End_Time      
       END) AS duration
FROM Table1 a
JOIN lkp_Numbers b
  ON b.N BETWEEN 1 AND duration/3600 + 1
```

One of the fastest ways to create a numbers table:

```
;with a AS (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
              SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)
SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS N
INTO lkp_Numbers
FROM a a, a b, a c, a d, a e, a f
```

If you have to do it with a cte, you can't use `IDENTITY` but can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead or some other method.  Numbers tables come in handy though.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8da9e/3/0)

Comment: Thanks @Hart CO identity column didn't work with in view I had to do

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hart CO identity column didn't work in view I had to do

```
row_number() over ( order by a.n) as N
```

also I got sub-query working

```
SELECT a.ID
  ,DATEADD(hour,n-1,start_time) AS Start_Time
  ,CASE WHEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time) <=  DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime)) THEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time)
        ELSE  DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime))     
   END as End_Time
  ,DATEDIFF(ss,DATEADD(hour,n-1,start_time),CASE WHEN     DATEADD(hour,n,start_time) <=  DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime)) THEN DATEADD(hour,n,start_time)
        ELSE  DATEADD(ss,duration,CAST(start_time AS datetime))    
   END) AS duration
FROM table1 a 
JOIN (select TOP 1000000 row_number() over ( order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
   cross join master..spt_values t2) b
 ON b.N BETWEEN 1 AND duration/3600 + 1
```

Thanks for the help again.